# How to retrieve data from document in Firestore db using HMTL/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

This should be something really easy to do, but I am lost...

My data is structured: UserInfo / UID / Attribute / Value

I am able to pull the data for a specific UID, but I cannot retrieve the Value for a given Attribute (lastname in this case).

````
db.collection("UserInfo").doc("TEST").get().then(function(doc){
           if(doc.exists) {
               console.log("Document data: ", doc.data());
               //console.log("Lastname1: ", doc.lastname);
               //console.log("Lastname2: ", doc.lastname());
               //console.log("Lastname3: ", doc.lastname.val());
               //console.log("Lastname4: ", doc.lastname.val);
               //console.log("Lastname5: ", doc.lastname.value());
               //console.log("Lastname6: ", doc.lastname.value);

               var mydata = JSON.parse(doc.data());
               var lname = mydata['lastname'];
               console.log("Lastname7: ", lname);
              
               //document.getElementById("b-lastname").value = doc.data.lastname.value();
           } else
           console.log("Document not found!!");
       })```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doc` object contains the document data (retrieved by calling `doc.data()`) as well as other properties (like the `id`). So in order to access the value of certain attributes within the data you need to do `doc.data().property` where `property` is the key for the property you want to access.

So to access the lastname, you would need to do `doc.data().lastname`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Aziz. So simple. Your first answer was perfectly clear.